# How to get information about Magento security patches?

Tags: magento-1, patches, security

Today a friend alerted me about a critical security update for Magento - **[SUPEE-5344](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/)**. I didn't see any articles about this patch on major IT websites. Even if I [google](https://www.google.nl/webhp?q=supee-5344%20magento) for this update, I see SE pages about this update, but no Magentocommerce information, except then the download page. The Magento commerce forums are read only.

**This makes me wonder - where can I find alerts, where can I subscribe to a mailing list?**

Comment: Detailed information about patch releases now also in the new docs: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/patch-releases-2015.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Magento has **very** recently launched the Security Alert Registry—a mailing list that receives updates every time there's a potential security vulnerability or Magento patch.

Sign up here: http://magento.com/security

Comment: "Your security is our primary concern." Seriously? Primary??? Why did it take that long? Well... better late than never!

Comment: The link changed in 2022, see my answer below

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately there was no public blog post or news (at least that I know about).

So the best ressource is definitely getting on the Magento Partner mailing list, where this was first announced. I don't know if you can subscribe to it without being a partner.

But besides that it was also tweeted on the official Magento Twitter account: https://twitter.com/magento

In my opinion that's not the best way to communicate things like these, but at least another ressource to get relevant updates.

Comment: Their tweet about this: `New CE/EE patch to address a potential remote code execution issue. Download from Support Portal or CE download page` (http://bit.ly/PNgTJI) I'm not much of a twitter follower, and stuff like this will be lost in too much noise. Still a good tip!

Comment: I've changed the approved answer as there is now a "Magento Security Alert Registry"... http://magento.com/security

Answer (score 4):

the official twitter account doesn't always alert about patches, take SUPEE-5944 for example. their is also no options on the magento site to subscribe for this kind of notifications.
I've set up an alert on google.com/alerts ("magento patch supee-"), it eliminates a lot of background noise

Answer (score 3):

Use http://twitter.com/magento as the official communication channel and also http://twitter.com/benmarks/. There you will be able to find the latest news and security updates for Magento.

Answer (score 1):

You can get email alerts about any new content in [The Magento CE Downloads site](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/) by using a web page change notifier, there are a few options, these are my favorite.

1. Versionista.com offers versioning for free, works quite well with the magento page.
2. If you use Chrome and are okay with notifications only while on your computer, [PageMonitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-monitor/pemhgklkefakciniebenbfclihhmmfcd?hl=en) is excellent and powerful extension that allows you to check only specific parts of the page or keywords. Such as checking only parts in ".release-download" (without quotes) every 29 minutes.

I'm using both methods.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update 2022

The link to the **Adobe Security Notifications Registration**
changed:
https://www.adobe.com/subscription/adbeSecurityNotifications.html